# Why does 2's complement sign extension work by adding copies of the sign bit?

Tags: assembly, binary, bit-manipulation, twos-complement, sign-extension

Let's take the example of sign-extending a 16-bit signed number into a 32-bit register, such as `mov $+/-5, %ax` `movswl %ax, %ebx`.

There are two possible cases:

1. High bit is zero (number is positive). This is very easy to understand and intuitive. For example, if I have the number `5`, left-padding with zeros is very easy to understand. For example:

   ```
                     00000000 00000101    # 5 (represented in 16 bits)
   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101    # 5 (represented in 32 bits)
   ```
2. However, the tricky thing for me to understand is when it's a negative number and we sign-extend. Example:

   ```
                     11111111 11111011    # -5 (represented in 16 bits)
   11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011    # -5 (represented in 32 bits)
   ```

Yes, I know that we just fill the upper bits with `1`. But what makes that work? Perhaps sort of an explanation on what 'properties' of the binary number makes that possible would help me better understand this.

Comment: same thing that makes extending the zero work.

Comment: invert and add one to negate a number so with pencil and paper do a 64 bit binary version of 5 and negate it then negate it back to a positive number, you will very clearly understand it at that point, even 8 bits is more than enough (4 bits is enough) to see how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an `n+1`-bit 2's complement number:

- The high bit (sign bit) has place-value `-(2^n)`
- The next-highest bit has place value `2^(n-1)`, and so on (normal binary place value)

For example, in 8-bit 2's complement, the bit-pattern with just the MSB set represents a value of `-128 = -(2^7)`.  With the top two bits set, it represents `-128 + 64 = -64`.

---

When we extend by 1 bit, the original sign bit is now a "regular" bit with place value `+(2^n)` instead of `-(2^n)`, so the value represented by the existing bits is now `2^n + 2^n = 2^(n+1)` higher than the original value.  (Or the same if that bit was zero).

The new sign bit has a place value of `-(2^(n+1))`, so copying the original sign bit is exactly what we need to balance that change in place-value.  (Or leaves it unchanged if zero).

The procedure for one bit of course generalizes by repetition for any number of bits.

(Normally we'd use `n` = number of total bits, like n=8 instead of n=7 for 8-bit 2's complement.  Then the MSB's place value is `-2^(n-1)`, and changing its meaning by extending with a new sign bit adds `2^n` if it was set.)

---

See wikipedia for more about how the bits represent values: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_from_two's_complement_representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_from_two%27s_complement_representation) - the 2's complement article is quite good but doesn't go into detail about *why* copying the sign bit works.

You could also try it on paper for some small examples, like sign-extending from 4 to 5 bits.  `-1` (all-ones) would be a good value to start with, making the math simple.  Or `0b1000` (-8) is another good choice.

Google found https://andybargh.com/binary-sign-extension/ which works through one 8-bit example.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent answer by Peter Cordes, we will see here about the general case of sign extending an n-bit number to an m-bit number, where m > n.

The n-bit number has the decimal value: [image: n-bit number]

While, the m-bit number has the value: [image: m-bit number]

The trailing "[image: common terms]" represents terms that are the same in both the numbers.

If you subtract the n-bit number from the m-bit number you will get:
[image: terms getting combined]

As you can see the terms get combined in a pairwise manner, as you pass through them from right to left. At the end, we will have:

[image: zero result]

Thus, we can see that the sign extension preserves the value of the number in the general case.

Courtesy: https://kumom.io/articles/sign-extension